# 10 millisecond data - need to group in 15 minute blocks and apply log average to each block

Tags: excel

I have a set of data taken at 10 millisecond intervals. I need to group this data into 15 minute blocks (9,000 milliseconds) and obtain the log average from one column and the 10th lowest percentile from the other (my data is in decibels).

Is there a way I can split the data every 9,000th row and form groups from this, and then apply a formula to each group - without having to repeat the process for each group? i.e. some way to set it up so I can just drag down results (I have two weeks of data.)

Comment: Sure, use an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

Comment: btw, 15 minutes worth of 10ms increments is 90,000 not 9,000 and two weeks worth of 10ms increments would be 120,960,000 entries. Even if you wanted to group together in 9000ms time windows, that would be 900 rows of 10ms increments, not 9000. Your question is vague at best, wrong at worst and completely unclear in general.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate average of rows 1-9000 in column `A` you can use following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*9000+1):INDEX(A:A,(ROWS($1:1))*9000))
```

If you drag it down, next one will calculate rows 9001-18000 and so on.